# How to create new columns of duplicate and unique values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, unique

I'm trying to use a .csv file with 2 columns (e.g. col1 and col2) to generate 3 new columns: a column composed of all the values in common (duplicates) that col1 and col2 have (col3), a column composed of the values unique to col1 (col4) and a column composed of the values unique to col2 (col5). I'd then like to export the file.

For this purpose I hoped to use `dplyr` with the functions `mutate()`, pipes `%>%`, as well as the other functions `duplicated()`, `unique()` and `write_csv()`. However, nothing I've tried so far has worked.

My data isn't practical to paste here, as it is tens of thousands of rows of categorical values (names), so I can provide a simple example of the type of data I am working with:

```
col1 <- data.frame(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
col2 <- data.frame(c("a", "c", "e", "f", "g"))
```

If the code is correct, I would like to create 3 new objects (columns: col3 for duplicates, col4 and col5 for unique values of each original column), which return:

```
col3 = a, c, e
col4 = b, d
col5 = f, g
```

and then save this file as a .csv, for example:

```
write_csv(col_umns, path = "data/col_umns.csv")
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you need `intersect` and `setdiff` assuming the `col1` and `col2` as vectors `intersect(col1, col2)`, `setdiff(col2, col1)` and `setdiff(col1, col2)`

Comment: Not sure I understand the output you're trying to produce. Do you want a data frame with `NA`'s in the rows beyond your answer, e.g. col3 = c("a", "c", "e", NA, NA)?

Comment: No, just a list of how many duplicate / unique values there are, without NAs

Comment: `intersect()` and `setdiff()` produce the results I want, thank you!

Comment: I have used `data.frame` to try and combine this into a data frame, but the differring column lengths prevent this: 

`gene_lists <- data.frame(col3, col4, col5)
Error in data.frame(col3, col4, col5) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 4425, 91316, 1144`
(using my original data)

Comment: @nicholasflamel It might be helpful to understand more about what you would do with your output .csv files. It may be more logical to store your newly created vectors `col3` `col4` and `col5` and original data `col1` and `col2` in a list or something else, instead of a data frame.